# ElasticSearch/Kibana | Why time works but not timestamp

Tags: api, elasticsearch, timestamp

New to the ES API.

I have a simple request where I want only yesterday's and today's logs, using `now/d-1d` and `now`.

Used the `time` field; it works fine.

Then tried the `timestamp` fields, and 0 rows returned.  Also tried variants like `@timestamp` and `_timestamp`.

Here's my example:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "snName": "SomeCommand"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "server": "QASERVERENG01"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "time": {
                            "lte": "now/d",
                            "gte": "now-1d/d"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The above works, but if I replace "time" with "timestamp" etc., nothing.

Comment: How does your index mapping look like ?

Comment: I do not know how to find what the index mapping is.

Comment: Call `GET your-index-name` and paste the result in your question